# BMI calculator in HTML only

Tags: html

I want to create BMI calculator in HTML only.
I already made this:

```
            <form oninput="wynik.value= waga.value/(wzrost.value * wzrost.value)">
                <input type="text"  name="waga"autofocus placeholder="Podaj swoją wagę">
                <input type="text" name="wzrost"placeholder="Podaj swój wzrost"><br>
                <output id="wynik"></output>
            </form>
```

Works fine but i have some issue. I got output like "0.002794" but expected output is 27,94.
How to change dot position? Removing all 0?. I can use HTML only.

Comment: That's not HTML only. That's JavaScript, because there is code that is executed (the form `oninput` value is actual JavaScript). And this is not an "HTML problem" or a "JavaScript problem", but a simple maths problem. Get a calculator and do that exact equation `waga / wzrost * wzrost` and see the result. Just think on what you have to do to have the result that you want.

As a tip, do a small HTML/JavaScript tutorial so you know what you are actually doing. I promise you that it will help you in the future so you don't waste time on small things.

Comment: 1. HTML is Markup Language and can't perform any actions. 2. You are using JS inside `oninput="... JS code here ..."`. 3. Multiply your value by 10000 (basic math)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's basic math question

Comment: You have to take care of the correct units: BMI is `weight (in kg)/height^2 (in m)` . You are obviously using `height in cm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you've entered the person's height in centimeters, while the standard BMI formula expects the height to be expressed in meters. So for instance don't enter 185, but 1.85

If however, you prefer the input to be in centimeters, then adapt the formula to this:

```
 wynik.value = 10000 * waga.value/(wzrost.value * wzrost.value)
```

```html
<form oninput="wynik.value= 10000 *waga.value/(wzrost.value * wzrost.value)">
    <input type="number" name="waga" autofocus placeholder="Podaj swoją wagę">kg
    <input type="number" name="wzrost" placeholder="Podaj swój wzrost">cm<br>
    <output id="wynik"></output>
</form>
```